# Variable in Unslider.js incrementing without explicitly being incremented

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to build a slider plugin similar to unslider.js . I have been poking at the code of this plugin for a while now (1 week ) . there is this function in unslider.js

```
_.play = function() {
            _.t = setInterval(function() {
                _.to(_.i + 1);
            }, _.o.delay | 0);
        };
```

now if i do the following :

```
_.play = function() {
                _.t = setInterval(function() {
               console.log(_.i); // new line added for testing 
                    _.to(_.i + 1);
                }, _.o.delay | 0);
            };
```

as each slider passes i get the following result :

when the first slide slides , i get :

0 // in the console.

when the 2nd slide slides , i get :

1 // in the console .

and so on .

if your wondering what _ is , then its basically `this` which refers to fn.unslider().

now _.i is set on line 59 of the plugin : [line 59 of unslider.js](https://github.com/idiot/unslider/blob/master/src/unslider.js#L59)

but where is _.i being incremented ?? i just can't see that part in the plugin . i have run like more than 20 tests , console.logging different variables in the plugin ,but can't figure out this part .

heres the plugin in action : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7s6docao/) .

it would be great if somebody could point me to what exactly is incrementing _.i in the plugin .

Thanks .

Alexander .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_.i` is not incremented, it is set in the to function (line 339 in your fiddler sample).

So the Unslider, passes an index to the `_.to` function and the Unslider/ Carousel... showes the I page. Internally, the plugin saves the index.

```
    //  Move Unslider to a slide index
            _.to = function (index, callback) {
...
                        _.i = index;
...
                };
            };
```

Comment: line 184 ? thats the line your talking about ? 

https://github.com/idiot/unslider/blob/master/src/unslider.js#L184 ?